# Data isn't being stored or the store() function not called

Tags: laravel, laravel-10

I think the store() function in my ProductController isn't being called. I tried using the dd() function, but it didn't show anything.

In my ProductController, I have the function store() that is supposed to save the data to the database.

```
public function store(ProductFormRequest $request)
{
    dd('test');
    $validatedData = $request->validated();

    $product = new Product();
    $product->category_id = $validatedData['category_id'];
    $product->name = $validatedData['name'];
    $product->brand = $validatedData['brand'];
    if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
        $productImage = $request->file('image');
        $filename = time().'.'.$productImage->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $imagePath = public_path('/images/products/'.$filename);
        Image::make($productImage)->resize(600, 600)->save($imagePath);
        $product->image = $filename;
    }
    $product->save();

    $category = Category::find($validatedData['category_id']);
    $category->products()->save($product);

    $brand = Brand::firstOrCreate(['name' => $validatedData['brand']]);
    $brand->products()->save($product);

    return redirect()->route('admin.products.index')
        ->with('success', 'Product added successfully');
}
```

And the form that is being used to create a new product looks like this.

```
<form action="{{url('admin/products')}}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @csrf
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
        <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
            <button class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab"
                    data-bs-target="#home-tab-pane" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="home-tab-pane"
                    aria-selected="true">Начало
            </button>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
            <button class="nav-link" id="image-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab"
                    data-bs-target="#image-tab-pane" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="image-tab-pane"
                    aria-selected="false">Снимка на продукта
            </button>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
        <div class="tab-pane fade border p-3 show active" id="home-tab-pane" role="tabpanel"
             aria-labelledby="home-tab" tabindex="0">
            <div class="mb-3">
                <label>Категория</label>
                <select name="category_id" class="form-control">
                    @foreach ($categories as $category)
                    <option value="{{$category->id}}">{{$category->name}}</option>
                    @endforeach
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="mb-3">
                <label>Име на продукта</label>
                <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <div class="mb-3">
                <label>Избери марка</label>
                <select name="brand_id" class="form-control">
                    @foreach ($brands as $brand)
                    <option value="{{$brand->id}}">{{$brand->name}}</option>
                    @endforeach
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade border p-3" id="image-tab-pane" role="tabpanel"
                 aria-labelledby="image-tab" tabindex="0">
                <div class="mb-3">
                    <input type="file" name="image" class="form-control">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary text-white">Запази</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

I want to create a new product with a category and brand from other tables. The form refreshes when I click the Save button, and nothing is saved to the database. I tried using the dd() function to check if the function is being called or not. It has to flash a message "test" on the page when the Save button is clicked, and the form must not be submitted.

Comment: Check `ProductFormRequest` if the authorization returns `false`

Comment: It returns true

Comment: What does `{{url('admin/products')}}` return? Also do you not mean `{{route('admin/products')}}`? Please show your routes.

Comment: run php aritsan route:list and check if it is true your route.

Comment: show your routes file.